# How create a real time application using python?

Tags: python, vue.js, celery, real-time, polling

I have a python backend using ***celery*** and ***Redis*** to serve long-running tasks. The app has a front end build in **Vuejs**. For these long-running tasks, I need to provide a real-time update to the user about the status of that task. The approach I think of is to poll the status endpoint to using `setTimeOut` function in my js code. Is there any better approach to handle this kind of use case?